# Which will be executed first, added column to entity or flyway migration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flyway

I added new parameter to my entity and want to populate this column in the db using flyway. If I write migrations file with INSERT statements, and run program will it be able to see the new column (will the new column be added to the db first and then only migrations be executed)? If not, should I write in my migrations file to add column first if it does not exist yet?

Comment: How are you creating your column if it isn't through migrations? Are you using Hibernate's DDL generation?

Comment: yes, I am using ddl auto generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway migrations are applied during application startup, so before Hibernate will validate the DB schema against the entities.

In your case, add a new Flyway migration script. First, in the script add the new column. Then, add your insert statements (if necessary).

By this means, as soon as your application starts, the Flyway script will be executed, your column will be created and inserted into and then Hibernate will validate the DB schema and find the new column.